# SSLProtocolException in Appengine Endpoints Android client on 1 of 31 clients

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I use an generated app engine Android client (jar lib). There are no problems on 30 of the 31 clients. But one Samsung tablet refuses to connect and gives this crash:

> Android: 4.4.4 
>   Manufacturer: samsung Model: SM-T533 
>   - Date: Mon Aug 03 09:49:03 CEST 2015
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0x743164d0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:1407743E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744
>   0x74509f1c:0x00000000)    at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:449)
>     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
>     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>     at
>   nl.stackoverflow.question.RestoreDataLoader.loadInBackground(RestoreDataLoader.java:37)
>     at
>   nl.stackoverflow.question.RestoreDataLoader.loadInBackground(RestoreDataLoader.java:20)
>     at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
>     at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
>     at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0x743164d0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:1407743E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744
>   0x74509f1c:0x00000000)    at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
>     ... 25 more

ApiUtils class:

```
/**
 * Sales API Utility functions
 *
 * Created by Roel de Brouwer on 29-4-2015.
 */
public class ApiUtils {

    public static final String APP_NAME = BuildConfig.APP_NAME;
    public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = BuildConfig.WEBCLIENT_ID;
    public static final String AUDIENCE = "server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID;
    /**
     * Class instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    /**
     * Class instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new AndroidJsonFactory();

    private Context mContext;
    private String mAccountName;

    public ApiUtils(Context context, String accountName){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mAccountName = accountName;
    }


    private GoogleAccountCredential getCredential(){
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(mContext, AUDIENCE);
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(mAccountName);
        return credential;
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve a Sales api service handle to access the API.
     */
    public Sales getApiServiceHandle() {
        // Use a builder to help formulate the API request.
        Sales.Builder salesAPI = new Sales.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredential());
        Log.d("RootURL", salesAPI.getRootUrl());
        salesAPI.setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
        return salesAPI.build();
    }

    /**
     * @return Sales Api
     */
    public Sales.SalesAPI getApi(){
        return getApiServiceHandle().salesAPI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the tablet to the latest OS version (crippled by Samsung) fixed the problem. (Still based on Android 4.4.4)